# Changing char* string in a C loop

Tags: c, string, loops, char

I am trying to change a string within a loop to be able to save my images with a changing variable. Code snippet is as follows:

```
for (frames=1; frames<=10; frames++)
{
    char* Filename = "NEWIMAGE";
    int Save_Img = is_SaveImageMemEx (hCam, Filename, pMem, memID, 
    IS_IMG_PNG, 100);
    printf("Status Save %d\n",Save_Img);
}
```

What I want to do is put a variable that changes with the loop counter inside `Filename` so my saved file changes name with every iteration.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should specify the pattern for the filenames.

Comment: You can construct the name of the file using `sprintf`.

Comment: Thank you both, perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file name string with sprintf and use the `%d` format conversion specifier for an `int`:

```
char filename[32];
sprintf(filename, "NEWIMAGE-%d", frames);
```

`sprintf` works just like `printf`, but "prints" to a string instead of stdout.

If you declared `frames` as an `unsigned int`, use `%u`. If it is a `size_t` use `%zu`. For details see your friendly `printf` manual page, which will tell you how you can for example zero pad the number.

Be sure that the character array you write to is large enough to hold the longest output plus an extra `'\0'` character. In your particular case `NEWIMAGE-10` + 1 means 11 + 1 = 12 characters is enough, but 32 is future-proof for some time.

If you want to program like a pro, look at the `snprintf` and `asnprintf` functions, which can limit or allocate the memory written to, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sprintf` to create a formatting string:

```
char Filename[50];
sprintf(Filename, "NEWIMAGE%d", frames);
```